# Form type - only numbers !

Tags: forms, post, input, numbers, submit

```
<html>
<form action="update.php" method="POST" name="ID">
<input type="text" name="ID" ">
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

How can this form accept only numbers and not "a-z" or ",./';[])(-=" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the javascript function isNAN to check if the value of the field "is not a number". So, I added a onclick event to the submit button to call a function that checks it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate() {

        if (isNaN(document.forms[0].ID.value)) { 
            alert("Please enter only numbers.")
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


</script>
</head>
<form action="update.php" method="POST" name="ID">
<input type="text" name="ID">
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate();">
</form>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript for verification. The actual code depends on whether you use pure JS or some framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<form action="update.php" method="POST" name="ID">
<input type="text" name="ID" pattern="[0-9]*">
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Simplest is to use pattern attribute and specify a regular expression. It works in all new browsers. 
in this case `pattern="[0-9]*"` , it will accept zero or more digits.
use `[0-9]+` if you want at least one digit.
use may wish using `\d*` or `\d+` e.g `pattern="\d*"`